# I want checkin and checkout functionality using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want 2 textboxs where I can insert checkin & checkout date. Checkin date should be current or future date and checkout date should be greater then selected checkin date

Comment: What you tried so far? Post it

Comment: Took 5 sec on google, and here is an example http://jsbin.com/seduseqici/edit?html,output

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the code in the link you provided does not contain few functionality like current date should be minimum date in select box else the rest is good.

Comment: @RadheshVayeda No but it give should give him a very good idea about what plugins can be used. From that point it should not be hard to find and change whats missing

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Bingo!! You are right in that case... I was talking specific about the question asked.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Its simple using default datepicker plugins of JQuery. Code in jsfiddle contains 2 text box one for checkin and another for checkout.

```
$( "#checkin" ).datepicker({minDate : 0, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
```

[Hit Me !! For code..](https://jsfiddle.net/nb76c2nc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtCheckin").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    var date2 = $('#txtCheckin').datepicker('getDate');
                    date2.setDate(date2.getDate());
                    $('#txtCheckout').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                    //sets minDate to dateofbirth date + 1
                    $('#txtCheckout').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
                }
            });
            $('#txtCheckout').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                onClose: function () {
                    var dt1 = $('#txtCheckin').datepicker('getDate');
                    console.log(dt1);
                    var dt2 = $('#txtCheckout').datepicker('getDate');
                    if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                        var minDate = $('#txtCheckout').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                        $('#txtCheckout').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="txtCheckin" />
  <input type="text" id="txtCheckout" />
</body>
</html>
```

Src: http://jsbin.com/seduseqici/edit?html,output

Comment: Whats the point in taking my comment and posting it as an answer.

Comment: Did not see your answer in comments,  i also googled at the same time. and find the same answer

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery & jquery ui and try this.

HTML

```
  <label for="from">From</label>
        <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
        <label for="to">to</label>
        <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

Inside script tag, try this.

```
<script>
        $(function () {

            var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $("#from")
        .datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,

        })
        .on("change", function () {
            to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
        }),
      to = $("#to").datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,

      })
      .on("change", function () {
          from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
      });

            function getDate(element) {
                var date;
                try {
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
                } catch (error) {
                    date = null;
                }

                return date;
            }
        });
    </script>
```